# Windows 10 hotkey (keyboard shortcut) for switching between speakers

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Many times per day I need to switch between different speakers, which I do using my mouse in these 3 clicks as shown here:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**I would much prefer if I could press a certain key or combination of keys on the keyboard to toggle between my 2 main sets of speakers (each of the 2 shown highlighted here).**

Is there some built-in Windows feature that would allow this? Or would another program (such as AutoHotKey, which I have installed) allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself in a long time, but [Audio Switcher](https://audioswit.ch/er) is a freeware solution for this.
Key-command switching between outputs.

I used to use it on all the media PCs here for many years [but now we switched to Macs, so my info is out of date].